# MyQSL Connector Добавил в библиотеку проекта,выплевывает ошибку

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-workbench, mysqlconnector

Хочу подключить БД к проекту.Закинул конектор в структуру проекта IntelliJ(community),все по инструкции.При запуске выдает:

---

**WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.211 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Drive  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)  at sample.database.DatabaseHandler.getDbConnection(DatabaseHandler.java:19)     at sample.database.DatabaseHandler.signUpUser(DatabaseHandler.java:33)  at sample.controller.signupController.createUser(signupController.java:81)  at sample.controller.signupController.lambda$initialize$0(signupController.java:55)     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)     at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)  at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)     at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)     at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)     at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)   at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$358(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:204)   at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:511)  at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107)     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:590)   at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:474)   at sample.controller.LoginController.lambda$initialize$0(LoginController.java:58)   at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)     at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)  at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)     at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)     at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)     at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)   at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$358(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)**

---

Подскажите что не так пожалуйста

[image: DatebaseHundler]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
package sample.database;
import sample.model.User;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseHandler extends Config {
    Connection dbConnection;

    public Connection getDbConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://"+ dbHost +":"
                + dbPort + "/"
                + dbName ;

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Drive");

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dbUser, dbPass);

        return dbConnection;
    }

    public void signUpUser(User user){

        String insert = "INSERT INTO"+Const.USERS_TABLE+"("+Const.USERS_FIRSTNAME+","
                +Const.USERS_LASTNAME+","+Const.USERS_USERNAME+","+Const.USERS_PASSWORD+","
                +Const.USERS_GENDER+","+Const.USERS_LOCATION+")" + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);

            preparedStatement.setString(1,user.getFirstName());
            preparedStatement.setString(2,user.getLastName());
            preparedStatement.setString(3,user.getUserName());
            preparedStatement.setString(4,user.getPassword());
            preparedStatement.setString(5,user.getLocation());
            preparedStatement.setString(6,user.getGender());

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Код текстом добавьте

Comment: Добавил код текстом

Comment: @VladBench и выделить в секцию кода

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Drive at ,,, -должен быть не Drive а Driver (Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Drive");)

Comment: @Дмитрий видел бы ты сейчас мое лицо)Спасибо)